# Не работает отображение Text своего Label в Desing Time в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Пишу приложение под Compact Framework 3.5. Создал свой компонент унаследовав его от Label. Основное изменение это автоподбор высоты label. В compact framework нет AutoSize.

```
 public partial class AutoSizeLabel2 : Label
{        
    static Bitmap bmpSizer = new Bitmap(10, 10);
    static Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpSizer);

    public AutoSizeLabel2()
    {
        this.Text = "Label";
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Text;
        }
        set
        {            
            Rectangle clientRec = this.ClientRectangle;
            clientRec.Inflate(-2, 0);
            this.Height = CFMeasureString.MeasureString(g, value, clientRec, false).Height;
            this.Text = value;           
            this.Invalidate();            
        }
    }    
}
```

Но при работе с компонентом в конструкторе форм, вместо заданного текста всегда отражается WMS_Project.AutoSizeLabel2. Пример в приложенном файле.[image: Пример]

Comment: Скорее всего просто не вызывается событие OnTextChaged. Попробуйте вызывать `base.Text`. а не `this.Text`.

Comment: Не отрисовывается именно в Design Time в конструкторе. При запуске приложения все более менее нормально. Только при первом присвоении почему то отрисовывается только половина высоты, в последующие разы все отрабатывается корректно. Поменял не поогло